# Isabelle: How to get datatype Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, types, isabelle

Manual was so kind to answer my first question, but now i'm at a lose.
I want to define two types much like in propositional calculus i want to have an atomic type and one more complex type.

```
datatype atomicType = aa | bb | cc
datatype complexType = combine complexType complexType
```

Basically this plus being abled to use `atomicType` instances as `complexType`. Oc i could define another constructor `"Up atomicType"` for complexType, but then i don't see how i can differentiate between both types in my axioms and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is like you suggested:

```
datatype complexType = combine complexType complexType |
                       atomic atomicType
```

The `datatype` command will automatically generate a lot of constants for you. One group of those are the "discriminators" of type `complexType => bool`. They allow you to distinguish between the cases of your type.

```
datatype complexType = is_combined: combine complexType complexType |
                       is_atomic: atomic atomicType
```

... or use the default names (described in §2.1.5 of the [datatype manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2015/doc/datatypes.pdf)).

With that, you can write down a property like

```
is_atomic x ==> is_combined (some_operation ...)
```

Comment: Doesn't this only "convert" my atomicType into a complexType via some function?

Comment: It embeds `atomicType` into `complexType` using a constructor (which is a function). Datatype inheritance isn't supported in HOL. (There is record inheritance, but that only works for product types.)